# How do I collapse levels of two haven-labelled vector variables to use in the polychoric function with fifteen other variables?

Tags: r, correlation, r-haven

I'm using a dataset that has been imported from a Stata dataset.

I have 17 potential predictor variables that I want look at for multicollinearity. They are ordinal so I've been trying to use the polychoric function. I get an error message when I run:

```
cor_matrix <- polychoric(df)

> You have more than 8 categories for your items, polychoric is probably not needed
```

Looking at my variables most have responses `1:5` or `1:7`, but there are two out of the 17 that have 10 possible responses `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,98,99]`. Levels 98 "refuse" and 99 "don't know" are not very important to my analysis, so I've been trying to combine levels 98 and 99 with 1 (1 is "does not apply").

Q. How often did the outside match the inside?

```
| Value    | Label            |
| -------- | ---------------- |
| 1        | DNA              |
| 2        | Never            |
| 3        | Rarely           |
| 4        | Less than 1/2    |
| 5        | About 1/2        |
| 6        | More than 1/2    |
| 7        | Lots             |
| 8        | Always           |
| 98       | Refuse           |
| 99       | Don't Know       |
```

```
match <- labelled(c(7, 6, 4, 6, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 99, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 5, 98, 4, 6, 7, 4, 8, 4, 3, 4, 6, 7), c("DNA" = 1, "Never" = 2, "Rarely" = 3, "Less than half" = 4, "About half" = 5, "More than half" = 6, "Lots" = 7, "Always" = 8, "Refuse" = 98, "Don't know" = 99))

newmatch <- fct_collapse(match, 
    "Not known" = c("1", "98", "99"),
    "Never" = "2",
    "Rarely" = "3",
    "Less than half" = "4",
    "About half" = "5",
    "More than half" = "6",
    "Lots" = "7",
    "Always" = "8"
)
```

The error message I get is:

```
.f must be a factor or character vector, not a <haven_labelled/vctrs_vctr/double> object.
```

The other variables in the data set are labelled vectors so I want them all to match once I've collapsed the levels in these two variables.

Comment: Use `as_factor()` to your variables beforehand to change them to factors.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but it turned out that wasn't my main problem. Unfortunately the polychoric function is still not working. I've even taken out the problematic variables from the list, and still can't get it to work. So back to the drawing board.

Comment: Two things that might help: First, consider the documentation for ```polychoric```, i.e. type ```?polychoric``` with the package loaded. Maybe the function does not accept ```data.frames``` but requires specific pairs or variables. Second, your items perhaps need the same number of response alternatives for a polychoric correlation. What happens if you only use it on variables with 5 responses?

Comment: No, it doesn't like variables with 5 responses either.